# Fsolve with variables,

Tags: matlab, optimization, least-squares

I have this matlab function,

```
function [f]=ErrorFun(a,b,c)
    global I     
    global phi

    f = sum((a+b.*cos(phi)+c.*sin(phi)-I).^2);
end
```

`length(a)=length(b)=length(phi)=length(c)=length(I)N`.I want to use fsolve, but I don't know how to do it. `ErrorFun` is a least squares problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says

> `X = fsolve(FUN,X0)` starts at the matrix `X0` and tries to solve the 
>      equations in `FUN`.  `FUN` accepts input `X` and returns a vector (matrix) of 
>      equation values `F` evaluated at `X`.

so you need to rewrite your function so that it accepts a single vector of parameters as its input. E.g., in your case,

```
function f = ErrorFun(x)
    global I phi
    n = length(phi) ;
    a = x(1:n) ;
    b = x(n+1:2*n) ;
    c = x(2*n+1:3*n) ;

    f = sum((a+b.*cos(phi)+c.*sin(phi)-I).^2) ;
end
```

then call `fsolve` with this function and some initial vector `x0 = [a; b; c]`.